# standard error of the reference category of the outcome_ multinomial logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, multinomial-distribution

I am working with a multinational Logistic Regression model where I have a 6-category outcome and have a number of predictors(independent variables).

I have set category 1 of the target as the reference in the model. I do get probabilities of being in all these categories including category 1 but I don't get the standard deviation of category 1 but i get for all other categories. 
It is understandable as category 1 is the reference. but,

Is there any way I can get the standard error of this category as well?

Comment: Did you really mean `multinational Logistic Regression`?

Comment: no, sorry, i meant multinomial logit model.